# Is there a quick way to deny all privledges for a user group?

Tags: acl

It seems to me that when I create a new user group they have access to everything and I maybe only want them to have access to one thing e.g. com_content.

I have to painstakingly change the priviledges for all items to deny and then leave only the one I want on.  I'd prefer if they were denied by default.

Is there a quicker or easier way to acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a **system plugin** that checks:

- admin / site
- component
- usergroup

and when the values do not meet you're requirements, then redirect to a com_content page (maybe with a warning).

Comment: I guess I could, it seems like overkill to build a plugin for each user group just for this reason, especially as it then needs to be supported/maintained for its lifecycle as the core already does this.  Not a bad idea though, I think it would be a reasonably simple plugin right?

Comment: Why not just create one plugin that redirects all components except "com_content" if the user group is > the highest id that you currently have for your usergroups in your database? 
And maybe add a parameter to exclude specific new User Groups that you might add in the future.

Comment: I guess if there are different use cases e.g. content writer, graphic designer they will have access to diffferent components.  So then I'm into plugins for each use case.  I think in terms of maintainability it's probably best to use the core for this purpose.  Interesting idea though, I'd like to build that plugin just so I can understand how they work.